# out of line definition for destructor in enabled-if class?

Tags: c++, destructor, template-specialization

How do I write the out-of-line destructor body, for a template class with an std::enable_if argument?

(I need this to write a decorator, adding an identifier to other object types).

Code:

```
template<typename T,
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X,T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
class IdentifiedInstance: public T
{
public:
    virtual ~IdentifiedInstance() = 0; // abstract base, still needs a function body
};
```

Body definition:

```
template<typename T,
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X,T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
IdentifiedInstance::~IdentifiedInstance()
{
}
```

This doesn't compile because `IdentifiedInstance::` should be `IdentifiedInstance<T, ???>::`.

**What is the second parameter value here?
How do I correctly write this?**

**Notes (1)**:

Visual Studio 2015 accepts this form:

```
template<typename T,
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X,T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
class IdentifiedInstance: public T
{
public:
    ~IdentifiedInstance() = 0
    {
    }
};
```

Unfortunately the code I write needs to also be built under linux (and gcc rightfully chokes on this form).

**Notes (2)**: I tried searching for this online, but most answers I found, referred to how to partially specialize the destructor only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
template<typename T,
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X,T>::value>::type* S>
IdentifiedInstance<T,S>::~IdentifiedInstance()
{
}
```

Just naming the second parameter.

I also removed the default value, because you may not give default values twice (declaration and definition).